# How would you unbind all jQuery events from a particular namespace?

Tags: jquery, events

Is there a "global" unbind function in jQuery, such that I'd be able to remove all bound events from a given namespace? eg:

```
// assume these are the events bound to different elements
$('#foo').bind('click.myNS', ...);
$('#bar').bind('keyup.myNS', ...);
$('#baz').bind('dblclick.myNS', ...);    

// magic occurs here...
$.magicalGlobalUnbindFunction('.myNS');

// ...and afterwards, the three binds from above are gone
```

All the examples I've seen for unbind require some elements to be selected first. I guess that technically, you could do `$('*').unbind('.myNS')`, but that seems *very* inefficient.

Comment: I don't think HTML has name spacing, which is what the events are bound to.

Comment: @jondavidjohn: This form of namespacing is something provided by jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/bind/ It's just a way of organizing event handlers to make it easy to unbind them without affecting anyone else's (such as in a plugin).

Comment: @jondavidjohn : no, but with jquery you can give an event its own namespace. So the question here is "is there a [jquery] way of selecting all bound events of x namespace"

Comment: @jondavidjohn: see here for more info http://docs.jquery.com/Namespaced_Events

Comment: The jQuery team should work on such a feature. That would be neat.

Answer (score 15):

You could add `myNS` as a class to each of the elements where you want to unbind the events.

Comment: that's what he says seems "very inefficient"

Comment: @user120242: no, OP said using * as a selector would be inefficient, because it would basically look for and try to unbind the event from every element on the page.  What mikerobi is suggesting is at the time of binding, add a specific class name to the element, and then later use that classname as the selector, so that you are only selecting the relevant elements.

Comment: IMO this is probably the best solution...assuming jquery doesn't already have something else built in...which it might... internally it keeps a list with the namespace...even if there is no official selector that says "select all elements with this event namespace", it should theoretically be easy enough to create a jquery plugin to do this..

Comment: +1 Sometimes a less "engineered" solution is the best, and I think that's the case here. This accomplishes exactly what was asked for, with no added risk of bugs.

Answer (score 13):

You need to use jQuery's [On](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and [Off](http://api.jquery.com/off/) methods. Use document as the selector.

```
$(document).off('.myNS');

$(document).on('click.myNS','#foo', ...);
$(document).on('keyup.myNS','#bar', ...);
$(document).on('dblclick.myNS','#baz',''');
```

then your methods could look like

```
$(document).on('click.myNS','#foo', fooClicked);
var fooClicked = function(e){
    var $this = $(e.target);
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Well done! This is super concise and makes proper use of namespace.

Answer (score 9):

You could always wrap $.fn.bind and then cache the necessary refs:

```
(function ($) {
    var origBind = $.fn.bind,
        boundHash = {};

    $.fn.bind = function (type, data, fn) {
        var namespace = '',
            events = [];

        if (typeof type === 'string') {
            // @todo check the allowed chars for event namespaces.
            namespace = type.replace(/^[^.]+/, '');

            if (namespace.length) {
                events = boundHash[namespace];

                // Namespaces can hold any number of events.
                events = boundHash[namespace] = $.isArray(events) ? events : [];

                // Only really need ref to the html element(s)    
                events.push({
                    type: type, 
                    fn: $.isFunction(fn) ? fn : data, 
                    that: this.length > 1 ? this.toArray() : this[0]
                });
            }
        }

        origBind.apply(this, arguments);
    };

    // namespace to be muffled. Feel free to qualify a specific event type.
    $.muffle = function (namespace, type) {
        var events = [];

        if (boundHash.hasOwnProperty(namespace)) {
            events = boundHash[namespace];

            $.map(events, function (event) {
                var _type = type || event.type;

                if (event.type.indexOf(_type) === 0) {
                    $(event.that).unbind(_type, event.fn);
                }
            });

            // @todo think of better return value.
            return true;
        }

        // @todo think of better return value.
        return false
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I removed the repo, so removed the related comment.

Answer (score 4):

Truly you are looking for a magical global function but as always with magic you can only get illusion, in this case, of simplicity.

There is also jQuery solution using [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or [.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) (which is only variant of live()).

Using `$("body").delegate("#foo", "click.myNs", func)` you also bind event and using `$("#body").undelegate(".myNs")` you unbind it. I use here "body" element but ofcourse you can use any element that is ancestor of all elements you need binding on.

It will make your "unbinding" work faster but again it will make your events respond slower.

Answer (score 3):

You need to hack into jQuery internals, here's a working demo of a simple implementation:

http://jsfiddle.net/nkMQv/1/

The main work is done in regular js loops and shouldn't be very inefficient as even this page contains ultimately only 106 items to loop through. You should of course use event delegation as much as possible to keep the amount of items in the jQuery handler collection as small as possible.

Comment: Yes the namespaces of handlers are unfortunately stored VERY deep in the cache object, that's why there is so much inner looping and tmp variables :( But if you hide that away and only use the public method you will never know how dirty it is

Comment: Yeah, I thought about your technique as well. I guess the real diff between our solutions is mine takes more space your's is gonna take more processing power.

Comment: I didn't notice there was another legible answer as well (yours). I think yours is better because mine is just thinking "in the box" and a quick brute force hack :P Although I would still use jQuery internals for removing the events since they take regular DOM elements and no need to waste efficiency on creating new jQuery objects.

Comment: This solution is definitely along the lines of what I was expecting. But given how deep into jQuery you had to go I think it will be pretty flimsy on future versions of jQuery. +1 for the fiddle though. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should add a class within the bind function

```
$('#foo').bind('click.myNS', ...).addClass('removeLater');
$('#bar').bind('keyup.myNS', ...).addClass('removeLater');
$('#baz').bind('dblclick.myNS', ...).addClass('removeLater');
```

and afterwards

```
$('.removeLater').unbind();
```

If `#foo` `#bar` and `#etc` are all the same element or small set of them, you could also do:

```
$('div, button').unbind();
```

but if you have a bound event you don't want to remove that wouldn't be a good idea

Answer (score 0):

you could override the bind method of jquery and thereafter and in the override store a reference of all the namespace and the corresponding events in an associative array and then access the array based on which namespace events you want to unbind. Code could be something like this

```
var eventArray=[];
(function ($) {
    var bind = $.fn.bind;
    $.fn.bind= function () {
    var result = bind.apply(this, arguments);
    var selector=arguments[0];
    var nameSpace= selector.split(".")[1];   //code to select the nameSpace eg. click.myNS o/p->myNS (update this if your selector has multiple '.')
    if(!eventArray[nameSpace])    //if the associative array does not contain the namespace yet
    {
       eventArray[nameSpace]=[];
    }
    eventArray[nameSpace].push(selector);
    return result;
};
})(jQuery);
```

Now with the eventArray with you could unbind as you wish. Code to unbind all events on namespace myNS will look something as follows:

```
$.each(eventArray['myNS'],function(){
   $(this).unbind();
});
```

Hope this is a good solution. please let me know if I made any mistakes.