# pjax/ajax and browser back button issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, pjax

I use pjax to ajaxify my menu links. This works fine until I use the browser back button. In my javascript file I use Common Script files (to load all the necessary js files when the user hits the url) and Script files with respect to each menu links (when navigated through pjax)

```
function myFunction(){
/*All the script files */
}

$(document).ready(function(){
myFunction();

/*pjax menu loading block*/
$(document).on('click', 'a[data-pjax]', function(event) {
      $.pjax.click(event, '#pjax-container');
      $(document).on('pjax:end', function() {
          myFunction();  
      });

});
});
```

Now when I navigate to a menu item and try to come back by clicking the browser back button, the script files are getting duplicated (eg: slider images getting duplicated and table sorting not working).How to overcome this issue?

Comment: any demo or working sample?

Comment: No . I do not have any demo right now. It is in my localhost.

Comment: Which pjax are you using? standalone, jquery-pjax or any other. I have used pjax standalone and we solved this issue for that

Comment: Its jQuery based pjax

Comment: Can you post your html code also, are you using only html or any server side language is also used? The pjax is defunkt/jquery-pjax one?

Comment: Yes the pjax is from defunkt/jquery-pjax. I am using PHP for server side. Html has nothing other than the attribute data-pjax in the anchor tags as given in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the url specific loading this way, create a queue of functions which you want to load and unload on pjax complete

The solution is based on js prototyping

```
// create queue for load and unload
var onLoad = new PjaxExecQueue();
var onUnload = new PjaxExecQueue();

// way to add functions to queue to run on pjax load
onLoad.queue(function() {
    someFunction();
});

// way to add functions to queue to unload on pjax load
onUnload.queue(function() {
    someOtherFunction();
});

// load function if url contain particular path name
onLoad.queue_for_url(function_name, 'url_section');

// check for url specific function
var URLPjaxQueueElement = function(exec_function, url) {
    this.method = exec_function;
    if(url) {
        this.url = new RegExp(url);
    } else {
        this.url = /.*/;
    }
};

// create a queue object
var PjaxExecQueue = function () {
    this.url_exec_queue = [];
    this.id_exec_queue = [];
    this.fired = false;
    this.indicating_loading = false;
    this.content = $('#content');
};


PjaxExecQueue.prototype = {
    queue: function (exec_function) {
        this.url_exec_queue.unshift(new URLPjaxQueueElement(exec_function));
    },
    queue_for_url: function (exec_function, url_pattern) {
        this.url_exec_queue.unshift(new URLPjaxQueueElement(exec_function, url_pattern));
    },
    queue_if_id_present: function(exec_function, id) {
        this.id_exec_queue.unshift(new IDPjaxQueueElement(exec_function, id));
    },
    fire: function () {
        if(this.indicating_loading) {
            this.content.removeClass("indicate-loading");
            this.indicating_loading = false;
        }
        if(!this.fired) {
            var match_loc = window.location.pathname;
            var i = this.url_exec_queue.length;
            while(i--) {
                this.url_exec_queue[i].fire(match_loc);
            }

            i = this.id_exec_queue.length;
            while(i--) {
                this.id_exec_queue[i].fire(match_loc);
            }
        }
        this.fired = true;
    },
    reset: function() {
        this.fired = false;
    },
    loading: function () {
        this.content.addClass("indicate-loading");
        this.indicating_loading = true;
        this.reset();
    },
    count: function () {
        return exec_queue.length;
    },
    show: function (for_url) {
        for (var i=0; i < exec_queue.length; i++) {
            if(for_url) {
                if(exec_queue[i].url.test(for_url)) {
                    console.log("" + exec_queue[i].method);
                }
            } else{                                                                                                                                                                        
                console.log(exec_queue[i].url + " : " + exec_queue[i].method);
            }
        }
    }
};

// before send
$(document).on('pjax:beforeSend', function() {
   onLoad.loading();
   onUnload.fire();
});

// after pjax complete
$(document).on('pjax:complete', function() {
   onLoad.fire();
   onUnload.reset();
});
```

Comment: This looks complicated. There has to be some other way just to destroy and initialize script variables I believe.

Comment: This is mainly for functions. You can create a object or array containing all the object variables that you have asigned. There is one link regarding the same issue but not sure it will be helpful or not http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15597625/pjax-and-firefox-back-button-issue. Out of curiosity why you need to destroy object variables, on complete of pjax you can just re-assign them as per your usage

Comment: I am just unbinding the event handler to remove existing objects and reassigning them. This is because if I don't unbind, the scripts are not getting executed properly and the sliders are getting duplicated.

Comment: What you can do is to add class while bindind event say $('#someclick').on('click', ...).addClass('removeLater');


and afterwards

$('.removeLater').unbind();

for same set if elements you could also do:
$('div, button').unbind(); check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923067/how-would-you-unbind-all-jquery-events-from-a-particular-namespace

Comment: I just modified the code and the question.Please revisit the question and let me know if you can help me. Thanks

Comment: experiencing similar kind of issue as reported here https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax/issues/321
In my case, the slider images and the thumbnail navigation icon are repeated/duplicated.

Comment: I don't have anything else in mind, did you try pjax:complete just a wild guess

Comment: Pjax: complete does not support popstate. They are suggesting to use start and end. Only the sliders getting duplicated. Rest works fine. Not sure how to overcome this

Comment: It looks like the plugin layout does not fit well with the bfcache and the popstate behaviour. Time to replace the plugin. Thanks for your help.